# Can I use Solr just for search an existing Lucene index?

Tags: solr, lucene

I use Lucene locally to index documents. I know how to use Lucene pretty well. I never used Solr but I want to run a web search using a Lucene index so I'm now looking into it.

Can I install Solr on EC2 let's say, and then instead of indexing documents using Solr, doing it locally using Lucene directly and then just coping the Lucene index from my machine to EC2 which Solr will be using for search?

I'm assuming it's possible as long as I keep the index on disk but would like to be sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible, you would only make sure to maintain the exactly the same index structure (defined by Solr schema). However, it would also mean that your configuration would be stored in two completely separate places -- e.g. each time you would change an analyzer in Lucene, you would need to synchronize this change in Solr XML configuration. I'm not sure what benefit would Solr bring in such use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yep, didn't think about it... I am planning to crawl some websites and then index documents with some new tokenizers that I wrote. It might take some time and thought would be better to do it locally than on the cloud (where I need to pay for that).

Comment: Nothing stops you from performing the indexing on a local Solr instance and then copying the index.

Comment: I see. I'm using an analyzer that I wrote, do you know maybe where in Solr I should include the files? Thanks!